# Proposal: moderately repurpose the [jargon] and [terminology] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

As things stand, the [terminology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag is kind of useless - the tag wiki excerpt reads

> Questions concerning the terms (words and phrases) which may be used to cover specific concepts, fields, or phenomena.

Or, in other words, "questions about words and phrases". But we already have tags for that - [words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words) and [phrase](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase)<sup>1</sup>!

A common thing on other SE sites is to use the [terminology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag specifically for terminology about the primary topic of the site - so in this case, that would be for terminology used to describe the Japanese language itself, e.g. things like "What is the Japanese word for noun?" or "What exactly is a 拗音?". This would make the [terminology](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag more useful as a classification device. We already use the tag in this capacity on questions like [Is there an easily accessible list of terms in the Japanese grammar written both in Japanese and English?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9/) and [How do you classify a word like "電子レンジ"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/).

We could then make better use of the [jargon](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jargon) by applying it to questions that are really about field-specific jargon, like [Clarification of hard to understand Japanese Mahjong rule](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/) (mahjong) and [How to call a wait pointer in Japanese?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9692/) (computing) and [Is there a strict usage difference between 耐性 and 耐容 in medical contexts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14141/) (medicine; already tagged).

Thoughts?

---

<sup>1</sup> Auxiliarily, it would be nice to have the [phrase](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase) tag called [phrases](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) instead.

Comment: I'm generally fairly cynical about tags on this site in general, but I like the idea of purging [tag:terminology], perhaps in favor of [tag:linguistic-terminology] or something similar.